# Python Script to Automate Refreshing an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, automation, refresh

I would like to automatically refresh my excel file.
Currently the code I have is not completely satisfactory because Excel asks me each time to click Cancel or OK.  I have two sheets in the Excel file.

Here is the python code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
Xlsx = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = True
Xlsx.Visible = True
book = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open('C:/Test_Excel/Essai_1.xlsx')
# Refresh my two sheets
book.RefreshAll()
book.Save()
book.Close()
Xlsx.Quit()
del book
del Xlsx
```

How to automatically refresh the Excel file without Excel  asking me any questions.

Thank you

Comment: Don't have Excel on this machine to test, but set DisplayAlerts to False (Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = False).  If your goal is to prevent Dialog prompts, you definitely don't want it set to True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = True` to `Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = False`, that should do the trick.

Comment: I put Excel.DisplayAlerts = False and I do not have a confirmation message anymore. however, the data is not updated.
The data in excel is related to PostgresSQL.

Comment: Thank you for your solution that answers my first request.

Answer (score 3):

refreshall() is an async function so you need to wait for it to finish before you do anything else. you can use Xlsx.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone() to accomplish this.

```
import win32com.client as win32
Xlsx = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = True
Xlsx.Visible = True
book = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open('C:/Test_Excel/Essai_1.xlsx')
# Refresh my two sheets
book.RefreshAll()
Xlsx.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()# this will actually wait for the excel workbook to finish updating
book.Save()
book.Close()
Xlsx.Quit()
del book
del Xlsx
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for the solution, it is very useful.